# Pop first element in the data frame cell using python

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

Have a dataframe with values

```
     name         zip
0   newyork     newyorkZip codes,10009,10001,10002,10003
1   London      londonZip codes,25103,25126
```

how to pop out  `newyorkZip codes, 'londonZip codes'` from zip columns

expected output

```
     name         zip
0   newyork     10009,10001,10002,10003
1   London      25103,25126
```

Comment: Please do add expected output in your post too in code tags.

Comment: added @RavinderSingh13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `str.partition`

```
df['zip'] = df['zip'].str.partition(',')[2]

Out[132]:
      name                      zip
0  newyork  10009,10001,10002,10003
1   London              25103,25126
```

Comment: series object has no attribute zip

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it's a little bit out of the box, but it should work

```
zip_updated = []
for i in df['zip']:
    i = ','.join(i.split(',')[1:])
    zip_updated.append(i)

df['zip_updated'] = zip_updated
```

After that you can go ahead and delete the older zip column by .drop() function

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
df['zip']=df['zip'].str.split(',',expand=True).iloc[:,1:].fillna('').apply(','.join, axis=1).str.rstrip(',')
```

output:

```
    name        zip
0   newyork     10009,10001,10002,10003
1   London      25103,25126
```

Comment: series object has no attribute split

Comment: @user12157180 check now

Comment: Please check my expected output

Comment: @user12157180 now check this oneliner

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following. Using regex.

```
df['zip']=df['zip'].replace(regex=True,to_replace=r'([a-zA-Z]+ |[a-zA-Z]+,){1,}',value=r'')
```

df's output will be as follows.

```
    name        zip
0   newyork     10009,10001,10002,10003
1   London      25103,25126
```